# How to add DropDownList in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new one for MVC.

I have a two tables in my database call 'company' and 'Department'
So One company has many Department.

In my project I add my data base to Model as ADO.net Entity Model.
I create primary key and Forging key.
So when I create a  new Department I want to show the company list in the drop down list.

I don't know how to do it?

I try like this

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.tblCompany.PKComID, Model.tblCompany)
```

but It it not working
How can I do it?

Comment: Shameless plug and therefore only a comment : Here's how I use it http://www.basarat.com/2013/03/htmldropdownlistfor-aspnet-mvc-usage.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have something like this

```
public class Company
{
    public int PKComID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Populate a `ViewBag.AllCompanies` property in your controller. Then use this code in your view:

```
@{
    var allCompanies = ViewBag.AllCompanies as IEnumerable<Company>;
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.tblCompany.PKComID, new SelectList(allCompanies, "PKComID", "Name"))
```

Comment: sorry. It is not working. It is says  --                                        Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.SelectList(System.Collections.IEnumerable, string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @user1348351 Sorry about that. I updated my answer to be more complete.

Answer (score 0):

you can Try this

Add Select list in model class as

```
public SelectList Company { get; set; }
```

In controller fill company table like

```
model.Company = new SelectList(CompanyList , "Id", "Name", PKComID);
```

Finally you can bind in view as

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => model.tblCompany.PKComID, Model.Company , "--Select Company--")
```

I hope it will help.